# Can Privoxy analyse or log all accessed files/addresses for further analysis?

Tags: data-transfer

I just finished setting up my raspberry pi and one of it's uses is being a adblocking proxy (especially for my ps3). It works like a charm for crunchyroll already but i'm having troubles with Spotify. For finding the ads on crunchyroll I used Charles and PC as a temporary proxy, but Spotify seems to detect charles and refuses to connect, but it works with privoxy enabled. SO: How can I check the addresses and files that goes through provixy? I'd like to find and block the ad location it plays between few songs. 
thanks

Comment: I got something, I had to uncomment debug options and set the logfile. 
Now I have troubles with analysing SSL connection. Privoxy can see only hosts but not requested files.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that this violates the terms of service.

Comment: yet the majority of pc users uses adblock on their web browsers and modded routers :) but lets not go offtopic too much

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't done, just that it violates the TOS. It is like speeding there is a limit, but most speed at least occasionally.

Comment: Yeah I know, I am just trying to learn and use my pi :)